# Can Dapper release database connection early?

Tags: c#, dapper

We are usinig Dapper to execute SQL in IBM's Db2 on a mainframe
Our code to execute SQL is pretty standard, I think. Get a connection from the connection pool and use Dapper to execute the SQL. Then release the connection to the pool

```
    using var connection = GetConnection();
    {
        return await connection.QueryAsync<dynamic>(sql, new { instrumentIds });
    }
```

The problem is that while it only takes DB2 a couple of milliseconds to execute the SQL, Dapper will use about 100 milliseconds to unpack thousands of rows with maybe 20 columns each

So the connection is also locked while Dapper unpacks the result, and evenutally our application is starved for connections to DB2

If the connection could be released by Dapper when the SQL is executed at DB2 and before Dapper unpacks the result, we could multiply requests we can process by tenfold without increasing connections

Is that possible?

I have tried adding elapse time logging around the ExecuteReaderAsync call in Dapper, and I can confirm that this call only uses 10 milliseconds, while the entire QueryAsync call uses 140 milliseconds

```
    private static Task<DbDataReader> ExecuteReaderWithFlagsFallbackAsync(DbCommand cmd, bool wasClosed, CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var task = cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(GetBehavior(wasClosed, behavior), cancellationToken);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($" ### ExecuteReaderAsync took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        if (task.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted && Settings.DisableCommandBehaviorOptimizations(behavior, task.Exception.InnerException))
        { // we can retry; this time it will have different flags
            return cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(GetBehavior(wasClosed, behavior), cancellationToken);
        }
        return task;
    }
```

Comment: Can you locate the problematic "holding onto the connection too long" part of the [Dapper source code](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/tree/main/Dapper) so we can check it out/submit an issue ?

Comment: @Claus I have added code to show my measurement in Dapper code. Does that answer your question?

Comment: `ExecuteReaderAsync` doesn't transfer the data, as far as I'm aware. But the data transfer part obviously needs the connection to still be open. Have you tried reading all the data but discarding it, to prove that the problem is actually the Dapper deserialization?

Comment: *before Dapper unpacks the result* - quote the readme from the repo: *Buffered vs Unbuffered readers

Dapper's default behavior is to execute your SQL and buffer the entire reader on return. This is ideal in most cases as it minimizes shared locks in the db and cuts down on db network time.

However when executing huge queries you may need to minimize memory footprint and only load objects as needed. To do so pass, buffered: false into the Query method.*

Comment: *it only takes DB2 a couple of milliseconds to execute the SQL* - that may be true but executing an sql and preparing a result set is one thing, dragging it over a network is another thing entirely. *Dapper will use about 100 milliseconds to unpack thousands of rows with maybe 20 columns each* - so there are at least 40,000 cells of data (thousands plural times 20), data length unknown (tell us the size of the columns?)- how certain are you that the 100ms is Dapper downloading all the data in eg 10ms and then holding the connection open while it takes another 90ms to create a thousand objects?

Comment: Incidentally, does your GetConnection open the connection too? If so Dapper will leave it how it found it (open) which means it might be open needlessly while your code does any processing, especially if you're relying on exiting a `using` to close it (and possibly worse if you're doing `using var` in a long block).. If opening/closing the connection is left to Dapper I'd expect it would close it asap, especially in light of that snippet from the readme I quoted above.

Comment: Could you expand the part of the question where you say that *evenutally our application is starved for connections to DB2*. How many concurrent connections are there and how big the pool is so that you exceed the pool size? (even for the sake of helping future readers to compare their issues with yours)

Comment: @WiktorZychla our connection string is very much limited by what our DBA department will allow, We have MaxPoolSize = 50, and Connect_Timeout = 5. Eventually we run out of connections and get an error "Connection Pool has reached the maximum number of connections"

Comment: What does it mean here *eventually* ? Often? Then increase the pool size. Pool size should only be exceeded under heavy traffic. Also, consider caching the data that is queried often.

Comment: @WiktorZychla So this is a financial application. "often" is daily. Usually when stock exchanges open.... Or when key numbers are releassed which the market did not expect... Then we se hundreds of thousands of transactions per second.... We use caching for some data. Should we use it more? Perhaps that could be part of the solution. Not sure

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments

As pointed out my measurement is incorrect, as ExecuteReaderAsync does not read the results

Modifying my measurements to more correctly include actually reading the result from DB2, reveals that almost the entire time is spent reading the result. Not in Dappers unpack

```
            if (command.Buffered)
            {
                var buffer = new List<T>();
                var convertToType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(effectiveType) ?? effectiveType;
                var swReadAsyncAndUnpack = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                var swReadAsync = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                while (await reader.ReadAsync(cancel).ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    swReadAsync.Stop();
                    object val = func(reader);
                    buffer.Add(GetValue<T>(reader, effectiveType, val));
                    swReadAsync.Start();
                }
                swReadAsync.Stop();
                swReadAsyncAndUnpack.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($" ### All ReadAsync took {swReadAsync.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
                Console.WriteLine($" ### All ReadAsync and unpack took {swReadAsync.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
                while (await reader.NextResultAsync(cancel).ConfigureAwait(false)) { /* ignore subsequent result sets */ }
                command.OnCompleted();
                return buffer;
            }
```

I tthink we need to involve IBM in this, as time spent with ReadAsync in IBM.Data.DB2.Core does not match the elapse time which our DBA can measure within DB2

Comment: *within DB2* doesn't sound like there is any network transit time there - I'd make sure your DBA is also bringing apples for you to compare :)